# How to write ngIf expresion with filter in angular 6?

Tags: angular

I want to write an ngIf expresion using filter like below which is in angular 1.x in angular 6

```
<span *ngIf="(metricsdata.Details|filter:{ckecked==true}).length!=0">* atleast one metrics column should select </span>
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `metricsdata.Details` ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: [You don't](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe). Do it in your component with a getter or another variable (or even observables)

Comment: metricsdata: any = 
        {
            name: "SELECT ALL",
            checked:false,
            Details:[
                {value:"abc",ckecked:true,id:2},
                {value:"abx",ckecked:true,id:3},
                {value:"abc",ckecked:true,id:2},
                {value:"abx",ckecked:true,id:3}
            ]
        }

Comment: i know pipes can slove my issue but i want write minimal code - @JB

Comment: @ravireddy you didn't click and read read the link I posted. Do it, and you'll see that Angular does NOT have a filter pipe, that's it's on purpose, that there is a rational explanation for that, and how to deal with the absence of a filter pipe.

Comment: thanks @JB for correcting me